# Generate JSON from SQL query

Tags: json, sql-server

I need a JSON string as below from the SQL query.

```
 {
    "DocumentType": "FFS",
    "DBSKeyData": {
        "ProducingPlant": "FRM",
        "ProductionOrder": "TEST_Order"        
    },
    "DDSData": [
        {
            "Method": "Print",
            "PrinterId": "Test_ID"                 
        },
        {
            "Method": "Fileshare",
            "SharedLocation": "Test_Path",
            "Path": "Z\\Test",
            "FileName": "Test.pdf",
            "Overwrite": "true",
            "Watermark": "true",
            "Content": "1"
        }
    ] 
}
```

I tried the below query to get expected JSON string:

```
SELECT top 1 
  labelType AS documentType,
  (
  select producingPlant,  productionOrder 
  from test T2 with (Nolock)
  where T1.ordinalid = t2.ordinalid FOR JSON Path 
  ) AS dbsKeyData, 
  (
  select Method, PrinterId, [SharedLocation], [Path] ,[FileName], [Overwrite], [Watermark], [Content]
  from (
     select ordinalid, 'Print' as Method,Printer as PrinterId ,'' [SharedLocation], '' [Path] , [FileName], '' [Overwrite], '' [Watermark], ''  [Content]
     from test T3  with (Nolock)
     union all
     select ordinalid, 'Fileshare' Method, '' PrinterId, [SharedLocation], [Path] ,[FileName] as [FileName], 'true' [Overwrite], 'true' [Watermark], 1 [Content]
     from test T4  with (Nolock)
  ) T    
  where T1.ordinalid = T.ordinalid 
  FOR JSON PATH
  ) AS DDSData
```

But it hasn't given exact result.

```
{"documentType":"FFS",
 "dbsKeyData": 
  [
  {"producingPlant":"FRM","productionOrder":"TEST_Order"}
  ],
  "DDSData": 
  [
 {
  "Method":"Print",
  "PrinterId":"Test_ID",
  "SharedLocation":"",
  "Path":"",
  "FileName":"Test.pdf",
  "Overwrite":"",
  "Watermark":"",
  "Content":0
  }, 
  {
  "Method":"Fileshare",
  "PrinterId":"",
  "SharedLocation":"Test_Path",
  "Path":"Z\\Test","FileName":"Test.pdf",
  "Overwrite":"true",
  "Watermark":"true",
  "Content":1
  }
]
}
```

Kindly give me some suggestions.

Thank You!

Comment: Why is this tagged with both MySQL and MSSQL?

Comment: Please add example data and table definitions.

Comment: Hi siggemannen below is table data .remaing data is static                                                            ProducingPlant ProductionOrder PrinterId DocumentType SharedLocation Path FileName
FRM TEST_Order Test_ID FFS Test_Path Z\\Test Test.pdf

Comment: Why are you using `nolock` all over the place?

Comment: The query in the question won't give any result because it's full of errors. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76709764/edit) your question to include sample data in the form of DDL schema creation and DML data population, and fix the query so that it doesn't actually error.

Comment: I think you're pretty close. You can use NULL to remove the keys instead of '', and use WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER to remove the array wrapper for DBSKeyData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a single scan of the base table.

Unpivot the `Printer` and `Location` values into separate rows and aggregate them in a subquery.

`dbsKeyData` can be created using special aliases with `.` in them.

```sql
SELECT
  t.labelType AS documentType,
  t.producingPlant AS [dbsKeyData.producingPlant],
  t.productionOrder as [dbsKeyData.productionOrder],
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
      ('Print', Printer, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
      ('Fileshare', NULL, SharedLocation, Path, FileName, 'true', 'true', 1)
    ) v(Method, PrinterId, SharedLocation, Path, FileName, Overwrite, Watermark, Content)
    FOR JSON PATH
  ) AS DDSData
FROM test
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

Another option for the subquery is

```sql
SELECT
  t.labelType AS documentType,
  t.producingPlant AS [dbsKeyData.producingPlant],
  t.productionOrder as [dbsKeyData.productionOrder],
  JSON_QUERY('[' +
  (
    SELECT
      'Print' AS Method,
      Printer AS PrinterId
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
  ) + ',' +
  (
    SELECT
      'Fileshare' AS Method,
      SharedLocation,
      Path,
      FileName,
      'true' AS Overwrite,
      'true' Watermark,
      1 AS Content
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
  ) + ']') AS DDSData
FROM test
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

Do not use `NOLOCK` unless you *really really really* know what you're doing.